# Resharper Shortcut keys messed up

Tags: resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, resharper-10.0

Yesterday, resharper randomly uninstalled after I had VS crash, after re-installing, nothing works correctly. I have reset VS's default key bindings and then enabled resharper's. When I first use a resharper shortcut, a menu pops up as expected asking me to select whether or not to use the resharper versions of shortcuts. I say yes and select apply to all resharper shortcuts. This is where the strangeness begins. Here at work we use code cleanup a lot (ctrl+e, ctrl+f), but ever since the crash and reinstall, I cannot use this shortcut. It recognizes the ctrl+e and opens up recent files and doesn't wait for the ctrl+f part of the shortcut. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you applied "IDEA/ReSharper 2.x" keymap scheme. Please reset keymaps once again and then apply "Visual Studio" keymap scheme here ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus.

By the way, a default Code Cleanup shortcut in "Visual Studio" scheme is "Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C", not "ctrl+e, ctrl+f" you mentioned

Comment: Thanks, although we definitely use E and F, so that is interesting.

Comment: Just checked it, Ctrl+E, Ctrl+F - it is a shortcut for ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode, so it is pretty the same as Cleanup Code, just silent :)